# Mathematica gives different zeros of polynomials

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, polynomials

I have defined the Jacobi polynomials in terms of hypergeometric functions in two ways. While calculating the zeros of Jacobi polynomials, Mathematica shows different values of first few zeros. I am confused with the correct one. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
sfact[a, n] === Pochhammer[a, n]

jacobi[n_, a_, b_, z_] :=  Pochhammer[a + 1, n]/n! Sum[Pochhammer[-n, k] Pochhammer[1 + n + a + b, k] (1 - z)^k/(Pochhammer[a + 1, k] k! 2^k), {k, 0, n}]

jacobii[n_, a_, b_, z_] = Pochhammer[1 + a, n])/n! * Hypergeometric2F1[-n, 1 + a + b + n, 1 + a, (1 - z)/2]

NSolve[jacobi[15, 8.3, -1.55, z] == 0, z]

{{z -> -1.00197}, {z -> -0.989872}, {z -> -0.946571}, {z ->-0.876951}, {z -> -0.781069}, {z -> -0.66255}, {z -> -0.524204}, {z -> -0.37}, {z -> -0.204121}, {z -> -0.0311152}, {z -> 0.144319}, {z -> 0.317478}, {z -> 0.483868}, {z -> 0.639596}, {z -> 0.78275}}

NSolve[jacobii[15, 8.3, -1.55, z] == 0, z]

{{z -> -1.00214}, {z -> -0.989586}, {z -> -0.946753}, {z -> -0.876849}, {z -> -0.781115}, {z -> -0.662534}, {z -> -0.524208}, {z -> -0.369999}, {z -> -0.204121}, {z -> -0.0311152}, {z -> 0.144319}, {z -> 0.317478}, {z -> 0.483868}, {z -> 0.639596}, {z -> 0.78275}}
```

Comment: Hypergeometric function is given by an infinite sum, but your first definition has only a finite number of terms.

Comment: It's hard to give any help if you don't supply code other people can easily copy; no one is going to bother retyping stuff from a screenshot.

Comment: Please include code in copyable form. Please include symbolic results for a simple case, such as `jacobi[4,2,7,z]` and `jacobii[4,2,7,z]` and the built-in `JacobiP[4,2,7,z]` to see if, at the symbolic level, your expressions are probably correct. If symbolically everything is good, then welcome to floating point world. For instance `z/.NSolve[JacobiP[15,5.3,-0.55,z]==0,z]` and `w+1/.NSolve[JacobiP[15,5.3,-0.55,w+1]==0,w]` should be identical in theory but are not. These are polynomials with large coefficients and so on...

Comment: @yarchik The hypergeometric representation of the Jacobi polynomial is
$$\frac{(a+1)_n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-n)_k (n+a+b+1)_k}{(a+1)_k k!}\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^k$$

Comment: @user293787 Thanks a lot. Using JacobiP, I got the zeros as in the published paper. But still have confusions with the zeros of the polynomial defined manually.

Comment: @yarchik My question is about the zeros of the Jacobi polynomials.

Comment: In any event, for rootfinding of Jacobi polynomials, it makes better numerical sense to just find the eigenvalues of the corresponding Jacobi matrix: `Eigenvalues[ResourceFunction["JacobiMatrix"][15, {JacobiP, 8.3, -1.55}]] // Sort`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank You for thie code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sfact[a_, n_] := Product[(a + k - 1), {k, 1, n}]
```

Your `sfact` is just the function [`Pochhammer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pochhammer.html)

```
sfact[a, n] === Pochhammer[a, n]

(* True *)

jacobi[n_, a_, b_, z_] := 
 Pochhammer[a + 1, n]/n! Sum[
   Pochhammer[-n, k] Pochhammer[1 + n + a + b, 
     k] (1 - z)^k/(Pochhammer[a + 1, k] k! 2^k), {k, 0, n}]
```

Your definition for `jacobii` is what you get for `jacobi` if you use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
jacobii[n_, a_, b_, z_] = jacobi[n, a, b, z]

(* (Hypergeometric2F1[-n, 1 + a + b + n, 1 + a, (1 - z)/2] * 
  Pochhammer[1 + a, n])/n!
```

The differences that you observed are precision issues

```
soli1 = NSolveValues[jacobi[15, 8.3, -1.55, z] == 0, z]

(* {-1.00164, -0.990395, -0.946253, -0.877127, -0.780995, -0.662574, -0.524198, \
-0.370001, -0.204121, -0.0311152, 0.144319, 0.317478, 0.483868, 0.639596, \
0.78275} *)
```

Note that the results for `jacobi` change with exact input

```
soli2 = NSolveValues[jacobi[15, 83/10, -155/100, z] == 0, z]

(* {-1.00223, -0.989436, -0.946852, -0.876792, -0.78114, -0.662525, -0.52421, \
-0.369999, -0.204122, -0.0311152, 0.144319, 0.317478, 0.483868, 0.639596, \
0.78275} *)
```

Similarly with `jacobii`

```
solii1 = NSolveValues[jacobii[15, 8.3, -1.55, z] == 0, z]

(* {-1.00214, -0.989586, -0.946753, -0.876849, -0.781115, -0.662534, -0.524208, \
-0.369999, -0.204121, -0.0311152, 0.144319, 0.317478, 0.483868, 0.639596, \
0.78275} *)

solii2 = NSolveValues[jacobii[15, 83/10, -155/100, z] == 0, z]

(* {-1.00223, -0.989436, -0.946852, -0.876792, -0.78114, -0.662525, -0.52421, \
-0.369999, -0.204122, -0.0311152, 0.144319, 0.317478, 0.483868, 0.639596, \
0.78275} *)
```

However, comparing the results from both methods using exact input

```
soli2 - solii2

(* {-9.66565*10^-11, -1.32849*10^-10, 2.83897*10^-11, 
 1.39112*10^-11, -5.60085*10^-12, 1.06459*10^-12, 
 3.10862*10^-14, -5.55112*10^-16, 8.32667*10^-17, -6.93889*10^-18, 0., 
 1.11022*10^-16, 3.33067*10^-16, -3.33067*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16} *)
```

**EDIT:** The built-in [`JacobiP`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiP.html) gives equivalent results with exact input.

```
jacobi[n, a, b, z]/JacobiP[n, a, b, z] == 
  jacobii[n, a, b, z]/JacobiP[n, a, b, z] == 1 // 
    FullSimplify

(* True *)

solP = NSolveValues[JacobiP[15, 83/10, -155/100, z] == 0, z];

solP - solii2

(* {-4.89355*10^-11, -1.84909*10^-10, 
 3.09808*10^-11, -3.90776*10^-12, -3.9404*10^-12, -6.37379*10^-13, 
 4.40759*10^-14, -8.88178*10^-16, 5.55112*10^-17, 1.04083*10^-17, 0., 0., 
 1.11022*10^-16, -9.99201*10^-16, 5.55112*10^-16} *)
```

To get better results use [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) with the exact inputs.

```
solPfs = NSolveValues[FullSimplify[JacobiP[15, 83/10, -155/100, z]] == 0, z];

solii3 = NSolveValues[FullSimplify[jacobii[15, 83/10, -155/100, z]] == 0, z];

solPfs - solii3

(* {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful clarification.

Comment: But as suggested above in the comments, when we take the in-built syntax JacobiP it gives different value, what I exactly want. How does it works?

Comment: Dear @PinakiPrasadKar, `NSolve` tries to numerically solve whatever equation you feed into it. To understand what is going on, one should not just compare the output of `NSolve`, but compare directly say `jacobi[15,5.3,-0.55,z]` and `JacobiP[15,5.3,-0.55,z]`. Perhaps look at something like [the Wilkinson polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial) for numerical subtleties of numerical root finding. In any case, in Mathematica something like `N[SolveValues[JacobiP[15,53/10,-55/100,z]==0,z],100]` should give you $100$ correct digits and you should be fine.

Comment: @user293787 Thanks a lot for the explanation.